# Open bitcoin-qt wallet with bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinj

I try to open the bitcoin-qt wallet with bitcoinj, I write this code:

```
private static final File WALLET_FILE = new File("C:\\Users\\Bapt\\AppData\\Roaming\\Bitcoin\\wallet.dat");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NetworkParameters networkParameters = NetworkParameters.prodNet();

    Wallet wallet;
    try {
        wallet = Wallet.loadFromFile(WALLET_FILE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't open wallet: " + e);
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Balance: " + wallet.getBalance());
}
```

But I have an error:

```
Couldn't open wallet: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

So I have two questions:

- Is is possible to do what I want ?
- If yes, what do you think could happen here ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitcoinJ has its own wallet format, and official bitcoin client its own.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Is it the same for the block chain ? Could I use the block chain downloaded by bitcoin-qt in bitcoinj ?

Comment: The blockchains are different too.